# Htaccess Redirect specified url with path to other url

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want redirect url to other url in the my website.

```
staging.mydomain.com/pathurl/
```

to this one :

```
staging.mydomain.com/newpathrul/
```

and I tried to add in httaccess file in my root project folder with this code :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} staging.mydomain.com/pathurl/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ "staging.mydomain.com/newpathrul/" [R=301,L]
```

but it's not work, could you tell what the correct htaccess code to redirect specified url with path to other url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`HTTP_HOST` Variable](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#examples) only has the `host part`, but does not have the `path part`.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^staging.mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^pathurl/(.*)$ /newpathurl/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Hi @Ben, thank you for your answer. I tried your code but it still not getting work..so I looking for reference again based your code and I find this code and it working when I applied in my httacess file `RewriteRule ^pathurl/(.*)$ /newpathurl/$1 [R=301,NC,L]`